# java zipoutputstream how to insert into zip 2 xml files

Tags: java, xml, stream

I am trying to add something to an existing code, so i would continue to use the structure that the project has.

To create an output zip file the code has the following flow:

```
                    String bakecaPath = configurationManager.getProviderParam(CommonConstants.THIRD_PARTY_PROVIDER_NAME, CommonConstants.BAKECA_FEED_XML_PATH);
        File bakecaOutputFile = new File(bakecaPath);
        bakecaStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(bakecaOutputFile));
        innerFileName = bakecaOutputFile.getName().replace(".zip", ".xml");
        ze = new ZipEntry(innerFileName);
        bakecaStream.putNextEntry(ze);

            bakecaWriter = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(bakecaStream, UTF_8);

            Marshaller bakecaMarshaller = constructMarshaller(BakecaAd.class);

               bakecaWriter.writeStartDocument(UTF_8,"1.0");
        bakecaWriter.writeStartElement(getRootElementName(Bakeca.class));


        bakecaWriter.writeEndElement();
        bakecaWriter.writeEndDocument();
        bakecaStream.closeEntry();

        closeWriter(bakecaWriter);
```

Where costructMarshaller is a method that I have in this class.

Now, I want to create 2 files .xml (i.e. newFeed.xml and newFeedAgency.xml) and put them into a unique file fcowrnfo.zip (the name is like this for security reasons)

I tryied to write 2 times the same thing, with only 1 servlet, but obviously in the file .zip I find only the second file that I have to write.

In the file web.xml:

```
             <servlet>
    <servlet-name>BakecaServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>it.antlia.wikire.servlet.BakecaServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
```

```
          <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>BakecaServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/bakeca_feed.zip</url-pattern>
```

If I make 2 filewriters, how can I attach them to the zipStream?

Or better, how can i solve this issue?

Comment: just to clarify, you want to create a zip file with two entries when your servlet is called? why not create the second entry right after you close the first `bakecaStream.closeEntry();`

Comment: yes, this is the concept. I want that when someone digits the url "baseURL"/servlet starts the download of the zip file that contains 2 files .xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a second file in the zip right after the you are done with creating the first file.

```
String bakecaPath = configurationManager.getProviderParam(CommonConstants.THIRD_PARTY_PROVIDER_NAME, CommonConstants.BAKECA_FEED_XML_PATH);

File bakecaOutputFile = new File(bakecaPath);
bakecaStream = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(bakecaOutputFile));

innerFileName = bakecaOutputFile.getName().replace(".zip", ".xml");
ze = new ZipEntry(innerFileName);

bakecaStream.putNextEntry(ze);

bakecaWriter = xmlOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(bakecaStream, UTF_8);
Marshaller bakecaMarshaller = constructMarshaller(BakecaAd.class);
bakecaWriter.writeStartDocument(UTF_8,"1.0");
bakecaWriter.writeStartElement(getRootElementName(Bakeca.class));
bakecaWriter.writeEndElement();
bakecaWriter.writeEndDocument();

bakecaStream.closeEntry();
closeWriter(bakecaWriter);

// create the next file
ZipEntry anotherFile = new ZipEntry("filename");

bakecaStream.putNextEntry(anotherFile);

// write to the second file here; you can write to bakecaStream again

bakecaStream.closeEntry();
```